# WIX: CustomAction can't find file after "InstallFiles"

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am currently working on a CustomAction library for reading and writing INI (outside C:\Windows) and XML files. I already looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780283/files-not-installed-when-executing-custom-action-in-wix) but the suggested answers did not help with my issue. The CustomAction (for reading a value from an INI file) I am trying to execute is defined as

```xml
<CustomAction Id="MyCustomAction" 
              Execute="deferred"
              Impersonate="no"
              Return="ignore"
              BinaryKey="MyCALibrary.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="MyCustomActionEntry" />
```

and scheduled as

```xml
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" After="InstallFiles">
     <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH]]>
   </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

As it is a deferred action, it receives data through a property:

```xml
   <Property Id="MyCustomAction"
              Value="File=[INSTALLDIR]cfg\MyConfig.ini;Section=MyConfig;Key=MyKey"/>
```

The (C#) implementation of my CustomAction looks like this:

```cs
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult MyCustomActionEntry(Session session)
    {
      try
      {
        session.Log("Begin MyCustomActionEntry");
        CustomActionData data = session.CustomActionData;

        session.Log($"Data: '{data}'.");

        string fileName = data["File"];
        string sectionName = data["Section"];
        string keyName = data["Key"];

        // ... check if all properties are set
        // ... removed for brevity

        session.Log($"- Parametrization: (File={fileName}; Section={sectionName}; Key={keyName}.");

        if(File.Exists(fileName))
        {
          session.Log("File found on disk.");
        }
        else
        {
          session.Log("File NOT found on disk.");
        }

        // ... actual INI Access - F A I L S

      } 
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        //... handle any errors
      }
    }
```

Using Orca, I see that the CustomAction is most likely scheduled correctly - the table `InstallExecuteSequence` shows:

```
...
InstallFiles   4000
...
MyCustomAction 4001
...
```

Of course, I now looked at the install log for hints. The log shows:
(In what I guess is the *immediate* phase):

```
Action ended <time>: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (F8:98) <time>: Doing action: MyCustomAction
Action start <time>: MyCustomAction.
Action ended <time>: MyCustomAction. Return value 1.
```

For what I think would be the *deferred* phase (further down in the log):

```
MSI (s) (F8:98) <time>: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=qjlzmwkb.ini|MyConfig.ini,SourceCabKey=<key>,DestName=MyConfig.ini,...,InstallMode=58982400,...)
MSI (s) (F8:98) <time>: File: C:\tmp\MyApp\cfg\MyConfig.ini;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (F8:98) <time>: Source for file '<key>' is compressed
...
Begin MyCustomActionEntry
...
Data: 'File=C:\tmp\MyApp\cfg\MyConfig.ini;Section=MyConfig;Key=MyKey'.
...
- Parametrization: (File=C:\tmp\MyApp\cfg\MyConfig.ini; Section=MyConfig; Key=MyKey).
...
File NOT found on disk.
```

After the installer finishes, the file is at exactly where I expepct it - the location referenced in the custom action.

I assume that the installed files should be available on disk after `InstallFiles` in the deferred stage of the execute phase for any CustomActions to access.
Has anyone else observed similar behavior and can give me hints on what else to do?

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the file you are passing is an INI file. Could it be that this file located in the IniFile table as opposed to the File table? And as such, you would need to schedule your Custom Action to execute after WriteIniValues instead of InstallFiles....

Comment: The INI file is located in the file table; the files to be installed are also all collected with heat - using the `HeatDirectory` element. Using Orca, I do not even see an IniFile table.

Comment: Are you sure that custom action runs deferred? Can you add your WiX markup for that so we can have a look?

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand. Is there any more to WiX markup than the three snippets at the top of my question?

Answer (score 0):

> ***Summary***: You can read values from an INI file using an immediate mode custom action and set properties that are used by Windows
>   Installer to write values to actual INI files the built-in way during regular installation (no custom action to write anything, just to read). [Advanced Installer Sample Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7_J6PcKcxY) (similar approach).

---

***Custom Actions***: A few things about custom actions:

- ***Problem***: I think **`Captain_Planet`** is right, the file does not exist yet, or you have a bitness issue where the file is somewhere else on disk when you try to access it.
- ***Beware***: [Just some propaganda against custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779).
- ***Debugging***: [You should attach the debugger via various tricks to get effective debugging going](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878332/wixsharp-debug-custom-action-in-console/52880033#52880033) (unless you do so already).

---

***INI***: A quick summary (to the best of my rusty knowledge):

- ***INI Write***: INI files can be fully written by MSI itself anywhere on disk

  - You can use properties to inject custom values: **`[MYPROPERTY]`**
  - The [IniFile table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/inifile-table) takes care of all of this, and it is working OK
  - Don't install INI files as separate files, use the IniFile table. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026584/129130)
- ***INI Read***: Windows Installer INI value searches support **only** files in **`%SystemDrive%\Windows`** folder (**`C:\Windows`**).

  - In other words: it is just reading values from anywhere that is hard (unless this has changed unbeknownst to me - I see different hacks here and there)
  - You can read values from an INI file using an **immediate mode custom action** and set properties that are used by Windows Installer to write values to actual INI files.
  - [There is sample code here to read INI files with VBScript](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_ini.php) (just to remember that it is there, not a recommendation to use as such).
- ***Video Sample Advanced Installer***: [See this video for how to do things with regards to INI files in Advanced Installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7_J6PcKcxY) (one of the [major MSI tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130))

---

***XML***: XML writing and reading was never a part of MSI at all (unlike INI writing which was). All major tools have support for XML writing and reading, and each tool does something slightly different by the looks of things.

- [Advanced Installer XML Support](https://www.youtube.com/user/AdvancedInstaller/search?query=xml)
- [Installshield XML Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419212/how-to-read-xml-nodes-value-in-installscript), and an article by [Robert Dickau](https://media.flexera.com/documents/XmlSearch.pdf)
- [WiX XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160583/added-new-application-setting-to-app-config-but-msi-wont-install-it-doesnt-ov)

> It is NOT advisable to roll your own features here if you can get by
>   with what is already out there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I already debugged the installer and was able to observe that the files are, indeed, not available on disk when my CustomAction is executed. When I look at the definition of the InstallFiles action, however, the files should already be there.
I am keenly aware of the WiX/MSI community's dislike for CustomActions, but limitations such as only being able to read from INI files in `%SystemDrive%\Windows` (which still exists) and the need for XML file manipulation make these CustomActions necessary.

Comment: You can use the built-in features for XML in WiX, Installshield, Advanced Installer, etc... was what I wanted to point out. Better tested. Still hard. Is there an existing INI file on disk that is not written to, or is the file simply not there? Where is the file installed? Did you check for bitness issues? **`%ProgramFiles(x86)%`** or **`%ProgramFiles%`** base?